# SQL - data testing - Oracle 11g lookup tables

Tags: sql

**issue summary**

- I need to use my client table to lookup name, address, etc
- my client table has 2 million rows, but only 167,000 unique clients, so I need
  to find the most current "max" entry for each
- most current entry is easy to find using a group by with max that gives me the "PK" for the rows I want ("PK" is max date & ID)
- I concatenate date || ID and use an IN to make sure I get the correct row from my subquery
- this runs slow since I have 167,000 values for my IN statement

**issue screen print**
[image]

**oracle version**
session Metadata (getDatabaseProductVersion):  Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**issue solution - exact same results, but much faster execution**
[image]

Comment: Maybe you should consider posting the answer here and then you can mark this question as answered.

Comment: Instead of creating a table called temp (as a tester your often don't have the authorization for) try the with clause. With this you create a temporary in-memory database. You don't need table-creation authorization for that.

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause